# Discord.JS v12 - Finding user by ID and kicking them

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Just as the title suggests, I have a problem with finding definitive answer that works.

I have tried using:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]); returns null
message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]); returns undefined
message.guild.member(args[0]); returns undefined
```

my code looks like this for now, but I have no idea why it still returns undefined and !offender line... Any ideas?

```js
let Offender = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) //returns mentioned user

// Was offender mentioned?
console.log(Offender)

if (!Offender) return message.channel.send(`You need to mention someone or give me their ID!`);
```

just as @Lioness100 said - it does return GuildMember promise and it doesn't trigger previously mentioned "if (!Offender)". But now we're facing another issue being that i'm getting "Offender(...).haspermission... is not a function" Once again - Any ideas?

```js
if (Offender().hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send(`You can't kick that user!`);
```

did as @a2br said, still returns "Offender.hasPermission is not a function"
code:

```
if (!Offender) return message.channel.send(`You need to mention someone or give me their ID!`);

if (Offender.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) return message.reply(`You can't kick that user!`);
```

Comment: Where do you define args?

Comment: In execute(message, args)

Comment: Try the fetch method again, but this time `await` it (it returns a promise)

Comment: Could you please give us the type of `Offender` when it returns it has no property `hasPermission`? (also, you should change the var name to lowercase, variable names like that are usually used for classes, it may be confusing)

Comment: i tried all three methods - all of them return some information about guild and user, not a guild member - so yes, it has no hasPermission property
(Thanks, i'll have that in mind when coding from now on)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is simple: `Offender` isn't a function. You should try to remove the `()` from `Offender()`.
Here's your edited code. It *should* work, although I didn't test it.

```js
const offender = (await message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) //returns mentioned user

if (!offender) return message.reply(`You need to mention someone or give me their ID!`);

if (offender.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) return message.reply(`You can't kick that user!`);
```